# Calling functions in a proxy contract

Tags: solidity, etherscan, abi, proxy-contracts

I am trying to call the withdraw function of this contract: [0x5d22045DAcEAB03B158031eCB7D9d06Fad24609b](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5d22045DAcEAB03B158031eCB7D9d06Fad24609b).

However, it is not visible in the ABI or source code. But I can see people have called this function in the past. How is that possible? How can I call this function?

Also, this function has an input parameter `ownerKey`, but I can't find any way to find what that parameter is.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply an interface of implementation on top of this proxy contract in order to call the intended functions. I've check the address you provided seems like it's nesting delegated calls where the implementation further delegated to other logic addresses, identified by the function selector.

Below shows an example of doing it on Remix, just change IERC20 to the intended interface to expose correct callable functions.
[image]

Edit:
I just checked the implementation of what's everyone calling, it is https://etherscan.io/address/0x2Dbc18A3ac126abE1fF90A83Bbc3947ff7912Afb#code. This might the ABI you looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this. Any idea what I can enter in the ownerkey field? I see no place to query this

Comment: @Phy_Amatuer Judging from the description of `getEthKey(uint256 ownerKey)` function. It's either an Ethereum account address or `starkKey`.

Comment: its uint256, so wont be account address. It is not starkKey either